How to disable F9 (process kill) option in htop
Is it possible to remove or disable only the F9 (process kill) option from htop? I have gone through the man pages and documentation, and all the layout options seem to be related to process/columns, not the function keys shown on the bottom line!
I want to do this because I want an unprivileged user to be able to use htop, but not be able to kill or meddle with any processes. I want them to use it just like a graphical version of top.
Note: I am invoking htop with a command line on my system where the user does not have access to the shell (bash).

Why do you want to do this?

This question is a means to an end. You need to be explaining what your goal is and why.

@vidarlo, and Matthew I have updated the question with more details

Only root or the same user as the process user can kill it. Are you running the processes with the same user?

@MatthewIfe its being invoked from a command line which runs with privileges, so htop does run as root!

You need to enforce least privilege. Dont log users in with privileges they dont need.

In my case @MatthewIfe the privilege is decided after they log into the command line.. anyway that is a different topic.. So, are you saying there is no way to control the options listed on the bottom line in htop?  (i.e. function keys are all permanently bound and not configurable?)

If you don't trust users, don't give them access to htop. Htop is not a security application; it's not meant to stop users from doing things; Unix security model is meant to do that. If you absolutely require this, run htop as a separate user, and it won't be able to kill anything anyway. Short of that, you would probably have to modify the source to do what you want.

well a chroot might be handy due you can limit all commands. any user can kill its own processes per default on a standard shell. I am unsure if cgroups(2) could help here

HTOP allows both the k key and f9 key for kill. You’d need to block both. The only way would be to remove or capture and block these key mappings from reaching htop. Yes you could do that, the parent process controls the stdin and stdout of an application, so you could have an app that calls htop filter those out. Having said that it’s a bad idea. It invokes more problems than it selves. Alternate ideas are:

For each user, make sure they are logged in as themselves and run htop for them; they can only then kill their own processes (ie the htop they are running), problem solved
Download htop source and just remove the k/F9 key bindings and recompile. This isn’t too difficult to accomplish.

Having said that, htop is an administration tool, not a monitoring tool. Difficult to trust that users won’t find a way to do some other destructive task with it. For example you’d need to block F7,F8,[,],s as well unless you want users to be able to change Niceness of processes.
I guess doing both 1 and 2 may be sufficient if you trust your users enough.
I don’t know if they login using ssh or whether this is provided on a webpage for example by using ttyd/gotty. If you are using ttyd for webpage viewing, you could instead use a more native interface than providing a tty to users. Though that is quite a bit of work. Alternatively implement your own using xterm.js a minimal code which only allows certain keys on server side to be passed to htop.
Honestly the more I think about it, modifying htop source to disable all actions you don’t want them to do is probably the easiest solution here. Source is here https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/tree/main or you can download a source deb/rpm for your distro for simpler compiling.
I’m back from vacation in a week, feel free to hit me then if you haven’t solved it and would like a hand and I’d be willing to do a bit of source grep and commenting out code.
